# No Wireless Connection Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I just downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 and literally could not know anything less.

How do I connect to my wifi? How do I set it up? Need help ASAP.

Comment: use `ifconfig` or `iwconfig` to see if your card is enabled. If it is in there, post your `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. If it isn't, use `lspci` to see if ubuntu can see it.

Answer (score 0):

First go to settings on the launcher. Then you would see additional drivers there, select that. Wireless drivers would install on clicking.